# Parse large single line JSON without loading whole file into memory

Tags: json, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to parse JSON from S3 CloudTrail logs and some of the files are a single line of 40MB of JSON when they are unzipped. I'm trying to avoid loading all of this into memory - is there a way to more properly read the entries 1 by 1 instead of loading the whole blob in memory?

I'm new to this so the only code I have right now is to Unmarshal the full line into memory

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder

Answer (score 1):

You can use json.Decoder() and process the file token by token as a stream. You can use Decoder.Decode() when you come to a place where you want to unmarshal into a struct.

json.Unmarshal() is essentially Decoder.Decode() called at the beginning of the stream.